# I have been getting this error of schema not registered. Is there anyway to resolve this error?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, reference, model-associations

I have been getting the following error.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCcW1.png

Following is link where i have defined schema and model but the error keeps coming that I have not registered schema of postModel.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1nQ6d.png

Error comes when I use the following callbacks to get all posts of a user.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFjUp.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't paste links to images of your `code / error messages`. It would be much better to copy/paste your  `code / error messages` into your question, including what line gives you that error. Please read [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please read why not upload images of code and/or errors on SO when asking a question [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors).

Comment: Line 11, it should be postmodel, not post